# Deprecation approach of jquery could be apply in java

Tags: java, jquery, deprecated

I liked the deprecation approach of jquery 1.9. first, they deprecates methods and then removed them in next version. For, backward compatibility, they provide migration plugin.

Similar approach could be apply in java as well by removing deprecated methods and providing migration jar for backward compatibility.

This way, use of deprecated methods in new projects will be minimized and developers don't need to check whether method in the api is deprecated or not.

But, java don't follow it. So, is there any flaw in the approach?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has something to do with the fact that java is compiled and JS interpreted, not sure though.

Comment: So, is it not possible in java? Then, alternate solution could be to have two jars. one with deprecated methods and one without.